# C# OutOfMemoryException while using StreamWriter to write to text file

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, using, streamwriter

I've looked at answers that are similar to this issue, but I still don't think I understand why I'm getting an exception.

I'm attempting to debug a section of code that is throwing out an "OutOfMemoryException" when writing to a text file, according to the stacktrace. The exception is being thrown from the following line:

```
WriteToLogFile("Found in EnumerateActiveDirectoryFilteredMembers: " + e.Message);
```

The WriteToLogFile method is as follows:

```
    static void WriteToLogFile(string strLine)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strLogFileName, true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "]: " + strLine);
        }
    }
```

It looks like StreamWriter objects can throw this exception sometimes, but isn't the memory being reallocated at the end of this method every time it is called? And isn't the use of the "using" keyword ensuring tht this object is being thrown away?

The file, by the time the exception is thrown, is only 13 KB - so what exactly is going on here?

UPDATE: The OutOfMemoryException is not the WriteToLogFile method. It's being thrown earlier, but I don't know where this is coming from... I'll add a skeleton of the try statement before the catch:

```
        try
        {
            if (objSearchResults.Count != 0)
            {
                // ADD TO DATASET HERE //
                string tableName = "tempADhold";
                DataSet domains = new DataSet();
                domains.Tables.Add(tableName);

                //add x number of columns
                domains.Tables[tableName].Columns.Add("DomainID", typeof(string));
                .
                .
                .

                // Get the object from AD.
                foreach (SearchResult objResultUser in objSearchResults)
                {
                    // Init variables and init formatting of strings for adding objects
                    string DomainID = ""; string UserName = ""; string Title = "";
                    .
                    .
                    .

                    objUserEntry = objResultUser.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    // Populate obj and LDAP path variables.  
                    // Perform edits before setting variables. 
                    //   Match strings to SQL Server table sizes.

                    // add objects in same manner:
                    // DomainID
                    if (objUserEntry.Properties["samAccountName"].Count > 0)
                    {
                        DomainID = objUserEntry.Properties["samAccountName"].Value.ToString();
                        if (DomainID.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() != "N")
                        {
                            WriteToLogFile("RECORD SKIPPED: Invalid N_Number: " + DomainID);
                            continue;  //skip this record
                        }
                        else if (DomainID.Length > 8)
                        {
                            WriteToLogFile("RECORD SKIPPED: Invalid N_Number length. #s ending in 'c' should be skipped: " + DomainID);
                            continue;  //skip this record
                        }

                    }
                    .
                    .
                    .

                    //set up array struct for adding obj

                    ADUserList[0] = DomainID; ADUserList[1] = UserName;
                    ADUserList[2] = ...; ADUserList[3] = ...;
                    ADUserList[4] = ...; ADUserList[5] = ...;
                    ADUserList[6] = ...; ADUserList[7] = ...;
                    ADUserList[8] = ...; ADUserList[9] = ...;
                    ADUserList[10] = ...; ADUserList[11] = ...;
                    ADUserList[12] = ...; ADUserList[13] = ...;
                    ADUserList[14] = ...; ADUserList[15] = ...;
                    ADUserList[16] = ...;

                    if (ADUsersIndex > 0 && ADUsersIndex % 2500 == 0)
                    {
                        //Add to dataset instead of array here...
                        if (InsertRows(domains.Tables[tableName]).Equals(false)) { return false; }
                        domains.Tables[tableName].Rows.Clear();
                    }

                    DataRow myRow = domains.Tables[tableName].NewRow();
                    myRow.ItemArray = ADUserList;
                    domains.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(myRow);
                    ADUsersIndex++;

                }
                //Write the last rows to the database.
                if (InsertRows(domains.Tables[tableName]).Equals(false)) { return false; }
                objSearchResults.Dispose();


            } //end "if (objSearchResults.Count != 0)"

            else
            {
                WriteToLogFile("Results: No Active Directory filtered members found.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           if (e is OutOfMemoryException) throw;
           WriteToConsole("Error in EnumerateActiveDirectoryFilteredMembers: " + e.Message);
           return true;
        }
```

Comment: Out of memory exception is triggered by the last drop, but may not be the main contributor to the problem. The code as posted is not the culprit.

Comment: Following the trace only leads me to the WriteToLogFile call... I'm new to using Visual Studio. Do you have a recommendation on tracking where this is being thrown if not at this call? Or perhaps figure out *what* is out of memory, such as a particular object, allocated space, etc?

Comment: Check this question and its answers: [Possible reasons for FileStream.Write() to throw an OutOfMemoryException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552828/possible-reasons-for-filestream-write-to-throw-an-outofmemoryexception). I am not sure whether it will really help you (but it seems to be, assuming that WriteToLogFile is perhaps called frequently), but it is at least worth a look...

Comment: What was the total working set of the process at the time when exception was thrown?

Comment: Try this: `sw.Write('['); sw.Write(DateTime.Now); sw.Write("]: "); sw.WriteLine(strLine);`. It avoids useless string concatenation.

Comment: I'm running another test. And yes, it is called quite frequently. I just realized that the StreamWriter object is never being closed. I'm attempting to do that now - we'll see what happens.

Comment: It's not closed, it's not opened, it's in a using clause, it's not the problem..

Comment: WriteToLogFile("Found in EnumerateActiveDirectoryFilteredMembers: " + e.Message); so how big is e.Message? Your entire AD in a string?  If that string is titanic i can see this throwing as you are duplicating the string as per @Lucas Trzesniewski comment

Comment: @tolanj - actually, I'm not entirely sure. This isn't my code, I'm only debugging it, but an exception is being thrown in a try statement, being caught without crashing, and when attempting to write out to the log file, throws this exception and *then* crashes. The output to the file is never written.

I'll attempt to run this without the e.message to see what happens.

Comment: It seems odd to create a new StreamWriter each time you want to write to the file. Could you create it once and reuse the writer?

Comment: @Moop: I agree. Again, not originally my code. And reusing/not reusing certainly wouldn't cause this type of exception...

Comment: Okay - I re-ran, and you were right, the exception is being thrown before. I've updated the above to include my try statement before the catch. The state of the objects are in fine order, nothing is above the allowable size limits. But basically this program is handling upwards of 32,000 transactions at it's peak. What could be throwing the Exception in the try statement? I'm not seeing anything that would cause this type of error... Then again, I could be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

This message is being throw trying to run

```
WriteToLogFile("Found in EnumerateActiveDirectoryFilteredMembers: " + e.Message);
```

*inside an error handler*

e is almost certainly an OutOfMemory exception already, but you handler is throwing when trying to log the message, 'hiding' the real stacktrace.

Add this to your error handler BEFORE the WriteToLogFile line:

```
if (e is OutOfMemoryException) throw;
```

This will then still cause the app to die, but give you the real StackTrace of original error.

Comment: Will do. The program has to run for a while to throw the exception, so I'll get back to you with results.

Comment: Okay - I re-ran, and you were right, the exception is being thrown before. I've updated the above to include my try statement before the catch. The state of the objects are in fine order, nothing is above the allowable size limits. 

But basically this program is handling upwards of 32,000 transactions at it's peak. 

What could be throwing the Exception in the try statement? I'm not seeing anything that would cause this type of error... Then again, I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: It wasn't all that helpful. In summary it traced origin to the call of the above try stmnt's fnctn, which is as follows: '                if (objADtoTable.EnumerateActiveDirectoryFilteredMembers(AD_R16_F1, AD_R16_F2).Equals(false)) { return -1; }' this call is in main. Main is getting group information from a config file (setting variables about yes or no to truncate, and assigning group "values" like 001, 002, etc. to local vars like 'AD_R16_F1'. Then it calls the function 'EnumerateActiveDirectoryFilteredMembers', passing in these groups. The try stmnt above is the meat of "Enumerate" fnctn.

Comment: But I'll post it as soon this current run is complete.